# Remove all characters except letters, '<', and '>'

Tags: php, regex

Say if I have a string:

```
$string="5 < 3 is @true"
```

I would like to get rid of the @(or any non-letter or number character) except for < and >.

Thank you for reading

Comment: Try providing more sample cases to clarify the problem. Include the input and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**REGEX**

Use the following and replace with an empty string:

```
[^0-9a-z<> ]+
```

And use the `i` modifier to make it work for Uppercase as well (Case insensitive match)

[`DEMO`](https://regex101.com/r/xU0mN6/1)

**Explanation**

```
[^0-9a-z<> ]+           any character except: '0' to '9', 'a' to'z', '<', '>', ' '
                        (1 or more times(matching the most amount possible))
```

**PHP**

```
$re = "/[^0-9a-z<> ]+/i"; 
$str = "5 < 3 is @true"; 
$subst = ""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: This preserves numbers, where OP wants to only preserve letters and angular brackets.

Comment: @Unihedro The OP disappeared and the answer could change when more details are provided...

Comment: @Enissay Thanks for answering, Worked Perfectly!!!

Answer (score 1):

The correct regex is the following:

```
/[^a-z<>]/gi
```

To replace, do like this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z<>]/gi', '', $string);
```

The workings:

- `[^]` detonates a *negative* character class (matches everything that *isn't* in the group)
- `a-z` matches characters from `a` to `z`
- `<>` matches the literal characters (it will match `<` or `>`)
- `/.../i` means that the match is case **i**nsensitive (making `a-z` match also `A-Z`)
- `/.../g` means that the match is **g**lobal

The last 2 are called *flags*  and are used to change the behaviour.

Multiple engines might have other flags (like the flag `e` for PHP, which matches a PHP expression and helps to keep a correct syntax), but the flags `gim` are available almost everywhere.
The flag `m` tells that the `.` (period or dot character) performs a **m**ultiline match (this means that newlines are matched too). This is not needed when the `.` is inside a character class because inside a character class, it will match the literal `.` character instead.

Comment: Thank you for adding the info on the regex characters!

Comment: @Bob You are welcome. I've added additional information regarding regexes. To try it out, you can check https://regex101.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^<>]/', '', $string);
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve letters as asked by OP.